# python plotting on top of a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is is possible to lay a second plot on top of this plot?
I'm getting this data from an embedded device and sometimes the process yields a value which I cannot plot into my distribution, but I would like to represent this missing value in some way if possible.

I was thinking it would be nice to put a red square on the Y=-5, X=phy for the x index who runs across this issue.

```
    top_0 = (umax - (umax % 10) + 20)                                      
    fig0 = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 12))                                    
    axes = fig0.add_subplot(111)                                           
    box_plot0 = axes.boxplot(matrix)                                       
    plt.setp(box_plot0['fliers'], color='red')                             
    plt.setp(box_plot0['whiskers'], color='black')                         
    plt.setp(box_plot0['medians'], color='blue')                           
    axes.set_title('Graph of {} {} Eye Openings'.format(self.engine, 0))   
    axes.set_xlabel(x_axis_label)                                          
    axes.set_ylabel('Score')                                               
    axes.set_ylim(bottom=-5, top=top_0)                                    
    yticks_0 = range(0, int(top_0), 10)                                    
    axes.yaxis.set_ticks(yticks_0)
    axes.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', color='lightgrey', alpha=0.5)                                                                    
    means0 = [np.mean(x) if len(x) > 0 else 0 for x in matrix]
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is just about plotting you can add the following code before `plt.show()` where I assume that `x_missing_val` is an array with the x coordinates of the missing values

```
axes.plot(x_missing_val,-5*ones(x_missing_val.size),'rs')
```